# How to Use a list all throughout my functions without making it a global variable (e.g. a list of items in a text based game)

Tags: python

Im Creating a text based game where the player needs to have some items in a list to survive an attack, and here i am using a list of items to store the items. However i tried to do it as a function, returned it from the function and put it as a parameter, However this doesnt work and i keep getting `missing 1 required positional argument: 'items'`
Here is an example =

```
def items(items_held):
    items_held = ["Money"]
    return items_held


def shop(items_held):
    print("You look around the shop for items.")
    print("Here is what you find that's useful for defending your home: ")
    shop_items = ["Wood", "Tool box", "Bear spray"]
    user_choice = input("Do you wish to buy these? (y/n) ")
    if user_choice == "y" and "Money" in items_held:
        items_held.extend(shop_items)
        print("You have bought the items.")
        print("You go back.")
    else:
        print("You dont have the money.")
    print(items_held)

shop()
```

I've Tried putting `items_held` into the `shop()` function as a parameter at the bottom, But that just says `items_held isnt defined.`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `def shop(items_held):` This defines the shop function to require one argument.  But then at the bottom of the code you try to call it without an argument.  So you need to decide, does it need an argument or not?

Comment: I tried to Call it at the bottom with Items_held but it said items_held wast defined @JohnGordon

Comment: That error is accurate, because `items_held`  only exists as a **local** variable inside the `items()` function.  It does not exist outside of that function.

Comment: However i returned it? Im a beginner, and I am assuming thats what returning it does, how would i solve the issue? @JohnGordon

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to actually call the `items()` function and save the returned value in a variable, and then pass that variable to the `shop()` function.

```
my_items_list = items()
shop(my_items_list)
```

Comment: wouldnt this make my_items_list a global variable, The challenge of this task is to not use any global variables.

Comment: Since you're calling `shop()` at the global level, any variable you would pass to it must therefore be global also.  The way this code is organized, you can't do what you want.

Comment: Well im open to change the way the code is organised, How about would that happen for me to not use global variables? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, you could change `shop()` so it doesn't take any arguments, and then call `items()` locally inside `shop()`.  But then the item list is only a local variable, and it will be lost when `shop()` exits, which doesn't seem like what you want either.

Comment: yeah that is the case, If this is unable to be done without global variables i will just do it that way and the teacher can mark it however they want @JohnGordon

Comment: I think the teacher actually intended for it to be done like I said in my answer.  Yes `my_items_list` is a global variable _outside_ of the shop function, but inside the function it is a _local_ variable.

Comment: Ok i will change the code to be used like yours, Thanks for help! @JohnGordon